# Are there options for `show_transfers` to change the date format?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, transaction-data, transaction-information

I recently made a transfer; and, when running `show_transfers` in the CLI wallet, the transaction reflects a date format of HH:MM:ss AM/PM.  All the other transactions in that output are reflected as YYYY-MM-DD.

Is there a way to change/customize the date format for individual transactions or for the overall output of `show_transfers`? If so, the way to do it is currently not reflected in the `help` output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no such options. There are two different date/time formats, selected based on the age of each transaction, as seen in src/simplewallet/simplewallet.cpp, function `get_human_readable_timestamp`. If the transaction is older than a day, the timestamp will be YYYY-MM-DD, otherwise it'll be the more precise HH:MM:SS.